# Moving objects together

Tags: java, bluej

Write a public instance method move() that takes two integer arguments representing the amount by which to change the values of the instance variables xPos and yPos. The method should return no value. It should make use of the provided method delay() to pause so that the effects of running the method repeatedly are visible, e.g. this.delay(20);

pauses execution for 20 ms.

Test your code by moving an instance of StickFigure and checking that it remains aligned.

My code I have is below but I cannot seem to figure out on how to move all 3 shapes together, only the triangle seems to move.

```
public class StickFigure
{
   /*Instance variables*/   
   private int xPos;//The horizontal position of a StickFigure
   private int yPos;//The vertical position of a StickFigure
   private Circle head;
   private Triangle body;
   private Rectangle leg;
   //   add your declarations here for part (a)(i)

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class StickFigure that 
    * provides a default stick figure near the bottom left corner of the graphical display.
    * 
    */
   public StickFigure()
   {
      super();
      this.head = new Circle (30, OUColour.PINK);
      this.body = new Triangle (50, 50, OUColour.RED);
      this.leg = new Rectangle (6, 50, OUColour.PINK);
      this.setXPos(25);  //sets starting position towards bottom left of Shapes window
      this.setYPos(220);
      this.alignAll();
   }   

   /**
    * Sets the xPos of the receiver to the value of the argument.
    */
   public void setXPos(int newPos)
   {
      this.xPos = newPos;
      this.body.setXPos(newPos);
      this.alignAll();
      //part (b)(iii)
   }

   /**
    * Returns the xPos of the receiver.
    */
   public int getXPos()
   {
      return this.xPos; 
   }

   /**
    * Sets the yPos of the receiver to the value of the argument.
    */
   public void setYPos(int newPos)
   {
      this.yPos = newPos;
      this.body.setYPos(newPos);
      this.alignAll();

      //part (b)(iii)
   }

   /**
    * Returns the yPos of the receiver.
    */
   public int getYPos()
   {
      return this.yPos;
   }  

   /**You will need to uncomment these methods when directed to*******/

   /**
    * Returns a reference to the head of the receiver.
    */
   public Circle getHead()
   {
      return this.head;   
   }

   /**
    * Returns a reference to the body of the receiver.
    */
   public Triangle getBody()
   {
      return this.body;   
   }

   /**
    * Returns a reference to the leg of the receiver.
    */
   public Rectangle getLeg()
   {
      return this.leg;   
   }

   /**
    * Aligns the head of the receiver relative to the xPos and yPos of the body.
    */
   public void alignHead()   
   {
      this.head.setXPos(this.body.getXPos() + (this.body.getWidth() - this.head.getDiameter())/2);
      this.head.setYPos(this.body.getYPos() - this.head.getDiameter());
   }  

   /**
    * Aligns the body of the receiver relative to the xPos and yPos of the head.
    */
   public void alignBody()   
   {
      this.body.setXPos(25);
      this.body.setYPos(220);
   } 

   /**
    * Aligns the leg of the receiver relative to the xPos and yPos of the head and body.
    */
   public void alignLeg()   
   {
      this.leg.setXPos(this.body.getXPos() + (this.body.getWidth() - this.leg.getWidth())/2);
      this.leg.setYPos(this.body.getYPos() + this.leg.getHeight());
   } 

   /**
    * Aligns all the body parts of the receiver to form the
    * StickFigure-type figure.
    */

   public void alignAll()
   {
      this.alignBody();
      this.alignHead();      
      this.alignLeg();
   }

   public void move(int xPos, int yPos)
   {
      this.alignAll();
      this.body.setXPos(xPos + xPos);
      this.body.setYPos(yPos + yPos);
      this.delay(20);


   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your `move()` set the xPos and yPos. so:

```
 this.body.setXPos(xPos + xPos);
 this.body.setYPos(yPos + yPos);
```

should be

```
 this.setXPos(this.xPos + xPos);
 this.setYPos(this.yPos + yPos);
```

**followed** by `alignAll()`

Then your `alignBody()` says: "Aligns the body of the receiver relative to the xPos and yPos of the head" but your method doesn't do that ...
It seems the head/leg are relative to body. So maybe the bodies X, Y should be relative to the xPos and yPos?

Comment: Consider the provided method alignHead(), which aligns the head relative to the xPos and yPos of the body of the stick figure so it is centred immediately above the body. Make sure you understand how it works.

Writing alignBody() is rather simpler as the body is simply placed at the coordinates of the stick figure itself, but alignLeg() will take a little more thought.

i.Write a public instance method alignBody() that takes no arguments and returns no value. It should set the xPos and yPos of the body to the xPos and yPos of the StickFigure.

Comment: I think you first want to get the numbers out of alignBody, using xpos and ypos instead. Then alignAll ought to handle what you are saying. Because the head will follow the body. And your moveAll should not then directly reset the body's xpos and ypos. It should reset xpos and ypos themselves, then call alignAll, which will start with moving the body.. And yes, I'm commenting here, because I think that's what this answer has in mind.

Comment: the idea here is right. But until you fix alignBody to not be hard coded, then alignAll will move everything back. Alternatively, alignAll should not call alignBody.

Comment: this.xPos + xPos works, but calling the parameter deltaX would be a lot clearer.

Comment: Consider the provided method alignHead(), which aligns the head relative to the xPos and yPos of the body of the stick figure so it is centred immediately above the body. Make sure you understand how it works.

Writing alignBody() is rather simpler as the body is simply placed at the coordinates of the stick figure itself, but alignLeg() will take a little more thought.

i.Write a public instance method alignBody() that takes no arguments and returns no value. It should set the xPos and yPos of the body to the xPos and yPos of the StickFigure.